# Optimal way to stack deck against adversarial opponent?

Tags: probability, game-theory, card-games

A two-player card game is played with a deck of cards numbered 1-52, which is shuffled and placed face down. Each player draws a card from the top of the deck, then both players reveal their cards and the player whose card has higher rank scores 1 point. Both cards are then discarded. The process is repeated until both decks have been depleted. The winner of the game is the one with the largest number of points.

Suppose you and your opponent can "cheat" at this game. Subjectively, when you reveal a card from your deck, that card is drawn uniformly at random from the set of all cards that haven't been played yet. Instead, before drawing, you and your opponent may each secretly choose to have their card drawn uniformly at random from a restricted subset of cards. You may choose any subset of two or more specific cards that haven't been played yet, and your opponent may do the same. (Neither of you has any information about whether the other person has cheated or which subset they've chosen, and the choice of subset is made before any cards are drawn that round.) The cards you and your opponent draw are guaranteed by the laws of physics to be distinct.

Is there an effective strategy for cheating that improves your chances of winning over playing fairly, or is the best strategy to play fairly?  I have tried to tabulate the payoff matrix for simple cases (n=2, n=4 cards) as well as trying to formulate an argument based on the symmetry of the game, but I haven't been able to prove a result either way yet. Any help is appreciated!

See also: I asked an earlier question about a similar game, where a single deck is split into two halves whose contents are known, and the opponent draws cards randomly instead of adversarially. [Optimal way to stack deck against uniformly random opponent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3125633/optimal-way-to-stack-deck-against-uniformly-random-opponent)  Unlike in that question, in this question both players are drawing from the same pool of unplayed cards (rather than both players knowing the contents of their respective halves and drawing from only those halves.)

Comment: I believe, but do not think the proof is solid, that you can't do better than choosing randomly.  Imagine playing against an opponent who draws randomly.  How can you do better than drawing randomly?

Comment: @RossMillikan That's my intuition as well. But what if against an opponent who draws randomly from the full set of remaining cards, you chose to draw one of the two highest-ranked cards remaining? Wouldn't that generally improve your chances of winning?

Comment: That would improve your chances of winning this round, but not the overall contest.

Comment: @RossMillikan I don't have a clear understanding of why that's true. It seems like if restricting to high-rank cards helps in the first round, it will also tend to help (to a lesser extent) in subsequent rounds as well.

Comment: No, because it leaves you with lower ranking cards for the later rounds

Comment: @RossMillikan But because you and your opponent are drawing from the same pool of cards, you aren't disadvantaged relative to your opponent are you? You both are left with lower ranked cards.

Comment: I was assuming the deck was split and then you were playing war.  Yes, if there is a common pile that you both draw from you want to pick high cards, but I thought "splitting" in the first sentence dealt half the deck to each of you.  You then have to play cards out of the half deck you got.

Comment: @RossMillikan My fault. I should clarify the game description in my question.  The deck is split but because the contents of both halves are unknown, the "cheating" process allows you to draw from a subset of /any/ of the cards that haven't been played yet.  I think if you try to draw pairs of high cards, your opponent can, as well, in which case I think you only win half the time.

Comment: If I understand correctly, at any point in time there is a shared deck of unused cards, and I can see all card values and then specify a subset from which to draw, right?  If so, it should be pretty trivial to prove that specifying the top $2$ cards dominates all other choices of subsets, and indeed both players should do the same and result in $1/2$ chance to win.

Comment: @antkam That's a correct statement of the rules of the game, and that strategy does result in a 1/2 chance of winning.  I am not sure how to prove that this strategy is optimal, but it seems reasonable. Maybe "Removing low cards from subset weakly increases chance of winning against any subset of opponent, as does adding high cards. Each round is 'memoryless', so best strategy in round 1 is best strategy each round."

Comment: Use the same $0,1$ matrix $P$ you used in your answer in the linked question.  I'm guessing the following are all true and can be (rigorously) proven with a bit of effort: (1) If you choose (row) subset $A$ and opp chooses (column) subset $B$ then your value is the the average value of $P$ restricted to $A$ and $B$.  (2) The rows are strictly ordered by inclusion, so $\forall B$, it never makes sense to choose a worse row while skipping a better row.  (3) Finally, the value is maximized when you only choose $2$ rows, i.e. the $2$ best rows.  This is the best choice $\forall B$.

Comment: @antkan Thanks! That sounds right except the diagonal has to be excluded from the count. I'll try to prove it.

Comment: Just put $1/2$ in the diagonal entries.  :)  BTW you will need the "strict ordering by inclusion" in step (2).  If the game were different and there were some kind of Rock-Paper-Scissors going on (e.g. $1$ beats $52$), then you cannot just pick the two rows with the most $1$s, and indeed such a game would have an optimal strategy that is mixed (probabilistic).  Your game has a deterministic optimal strategy only because there is no R-P-S going on.

Comment: Why would putting 1/2 on the diagonal give the correct value?  If I choose {51,52} and my opponent chooses {50,51,52} then there are 6 matchups. Two can't happen because they're on the diagonal, I win three, and lose one. I win 75% of the time. If I instead compute putting  1/2 on diagonal, I get 4 total points out of 6 matchups, which is 2/3.

Comment: ha, you're right, i cannot put $1/2$ on the diagonal.  my bad.

Answer (score 2):

**Theorem:** The optimal strategy is for both players to cheat each turn by choosing the two cards of highest rank. In this case, because you and your opponent are symmetric, the probability of winning is 50%.

*Proof*.

1. If you draw the card of highest rank, you will win against any card your opponent draws with certainty. If you draw the card of next-highest rank, you will win against any card your opponent draws, except if your opponent draws the card of highest rank. All lower-ranked cards are less likely to win than these two against any given subset of cards your opponent chooses. Therefore to optimize your expected winnings, you should cheat by choosing the two cards of highest rank. (So, by symmetry, should your opponent. but let's explore in more detail.)
2. Suppose your opponent chooses a subset of $k$ cards. If you draw the card of highest rank, you win with certainty. If you draw the card of next-highest rank, you win unless they draw the card of highest rank. That probability is $1/k$ if their subset doesn't contain the card of next highest rank, or $1/(k-1)$ if it does (because your opponent cannot  draw the same card as you).
3. Therefore against your strategy, your opponent should: include the card of highest rank, so as not to lose with certainty; include the card of next-highest rank so that the probability of winning otherwise is $1/(k-1)$ instead of $1/k$; and include no other cards so that $k=2$ is minimal.
4. In this case, each player will win the round with probability 50%, by the symmetry of their positions, and also because the enumerated outcomes are [highest, next-highest] or [next-highest, highest].
5. Every round has at least two cards remaining in the deck. Because our considerations don't otherwise depend on the number of cards in the deck, this same per-round strategy applies in all subsequent rounds. Your probability of winning is 50%.

Answer (score 0):

Your linked question has an answer that shows you cannot do better against a random opponent than to be random yourself.  That shows your opponent cannot be sure to do better against you than by playing randomly, so both of you should play randomly.  Now symmetry says you win with probability $\frac 12$ if draws are split.

Of course, if you know something about your opponent's tendencies, you can take advantage of that to improve your odds.  If you play randomly, you avoid the risk that your opponent can take advantage of your tendencies.

Comment: For clarity, I have rewritten the question into an equivalent form using only one shared pile.  This answer works if both players have separate piles with known contents that they draw from, but not if they draw from a shared pile --- hopefully the clarification helps.